# Sending back-to-back POST requests using Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python script to scrape data from this link: http://emma.msrb.org/MarketActivity/RecentOS.aspx. I've already configured my script to bypass the confirmation page (using a cookie), and I've figured out how to use a POST request to get to "All New Issues" rather than the default of "Today", but now I need to cycle through all of the 19 pages.

The POST request looks like this: `ctl00$gridViewPagingUserControl$page2LinkButton`, but using that doesn't get me what I need.

I'm using the Python Requests module, but I've also tried it with urllib/urllib2 and that doesn't seem to work either.

Basically, how can I send multiple/back-to-back POST requests to get to the pages I need?

My sample code is below. Using `post_requests_1` works fine, but `post_requests_2` does not.

```
# Cookies
cp = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
cj = cp.cookiejar
cj.set_cookie(cookielib.Cookie(0, 'Disclaimer', '247245968.1342815275.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)', '80', False, '.emma.msrb.org', True, False, '/', True, False, None, False, None, None, None))

post_requests_1 = { r'__EVENTTARGET' : r'ctl00$mainContentArea$allNewIssuesLinkButton', r'__EVENTARGUMENT' : r'' }
post_requests_2 = { r'__EVENTTARGET' : r'ctl00$mainContentArea$gridViewPagingUserControl$page2LinkButton', r'__EVENTARGUMENT' : r'' }
html = requests.post('http://emma.msrb.org/MarketActivity/RecentOS.aspx', data = post_requests_1, cookies = cj)
print html.text.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Consider using selenium.

Comment: Well, what happens when you use `post_requests_2`? Also, try reversing the order of requests to make sure the problem really is the fact that you're sending back to back requests, rather than being that your request data is incorrect.

Comment: `post_requests_2` doesn't get me what I need.  
  
To clarify: The link to the page I want is not on the original page, i.e. from a browser, you would have to make two clicks: first onto "All New Issues" and then to the page number you want. So the POST request to the specific page doesn't work. How can I send two POST requests back-to-back to get to the second page right away?